# How to make the "~~" in Windows 7 search default

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search

From experimental data, I try to put in some "metadata" directly into the filename (for various compatibility reasons), one such example is:

```
2-187a_cc_f5p5Hz_tc1s_Vds5V_Rds100MO_T0p445K_Ch75_VgSwV_B-0p05T_rH Set_1up
```

What you'll notice is that the string "0p**" comes up twice (and is often present 1-4 times). The problem I have is that the default filename search in windows 7 only shows up the last instance of "0p*". For example, if I know I am looking for "0p445" and type "Name:0p44" into the search box in explorer, I will not find the above file name.

By looking at the [Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs, I found I can use

```
Name:~~0p44
```

To find the filenames I would want.

**Question**: If possible, how can I change the default windows search to use "~~" in filename search?

Answer (score 0):

You could save your search and edit this each time you want to use this option but i only use "Search everything", blazing fast, free, portable and supports regular expressions, it can't look inside the files itself though.